# Runtime error in correct code for large value

Tags: c++, runtime-error

So, I was working on a C++ program that would list primes upto a specified number **N**.

I wanted to write a code that'd be deterministic, faster than trial division and easy to implement. I learnt about Sieve of Eratosthenes recently and tried to use that.

As expected, it uses a lot of memory but the run-time is quite fast. Now, my question is :

- Why does [this program](http://ideone.com/NdJBOR) give run-time error when **N**=115800 even when it [runs perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/PoN8Uy) with **N**=115700 in 0.02 secs and 3456 KB memory usage (on Ideone) ?

Clearly, this shouldn't be a memory issue since it's mentioned in the Ideone FAQ that the memory limit is 256 MB which is quite huge! I can't understand why the runtime-error is happening when the algorithm is correct and there's no memory issue!

Is it because the `char` array `arr` in my code has too many elements when **N**=115800 ?

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain your downvote. :|

Comment: You haven't supplied any code for us to look at.  StackOverflow isn't a crystal ball.  If the algorithm is perfect, then your code can't be.

Comment: @LukePark, he *did* provide two sample code !

Comment: @LukePark, are you blind?

Comment: Wow, 2 downvotes on a genuine and legit question! Just WOW!

Comment: @tom_cruise no need to be mean, that's is not going to help you around here. From the looks of it, it might just be an issue with Ideone.com, if you try on a regular IDE (I went with Visual Studio 2013), it works just fine. You might want to take it up with Ideone.

Comment: Apologies, the links weren't highlighted in my browser.  I'm on a very old version of IE.  Sorry.

Comment: I just tried your code using gcc and it runs fine for me.  Are you compiling online?

Comment: @LukePark, yeah. At Ideone. C++14 (gcc-5.1)

Comment: ideone has an output limit of 64k, read the FAQ. Also read the stackoverflow help page and the close vote if you want to know why you were downvoted.

Comment: @user657267, ah, thanks! I don't know how but I missed that earlier. You should post that comment as an answer and then I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor code nitpick not related to the problem. You may want to change:

```
if(arr[i]==NULL)
```

to:

```
if(arr[i]==0)
```

You want to be comparing your character arrays with `0` (not `NULL`). This isn't the cause of your problem.

The problem on Ideone is that they restrict the total amount of code, input, and output to 64kb. It just so happens that with `N=115800` you reach that limit. This can be found buried in the [FAQ](https://ideone.com/faq):

> What is the size limit for the source code, input and output?
>   64 kB.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but since I didn't get any error, I didn't bother changing it (I'm a teenager, therefore I'm lazy). Also, I think that since my code worked without errors, 0 (without the quotes) might just be equivalent to `NULL` when it's in a `char` variable in C++.

Comment: If you compile with extra warning checks (like `-Wall` on gcc/g++) it will likely warn you about it.